# Prevent DIVS from moving

Tags: css, html, overflow

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the tags inside a DIV from moving down when the window resize is smaller.

I want the links always to be on the right size with 100% window.

I would like the tags all remain horizontal and not move when the browser window is smaller.

Here is my link:  http://jsfiddle.net/B9WBF/

```
<div class="topnav">


<a href="contact.htm">LINK 1</a>
<a href="contact.htm">LINK 2</a>
<a href="contact.htm">LINK 3</a>
<a href="contact.htm">LINK 4</a>
<a href="contact.htm">LINK 5</a>


<div id="logo" href="home.htm"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you post your desired result image what exactly do you want @Erik

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, It seems you want to keep the `parent div` and the `child div` in a single line even the user resizes the window.. If so then Instead of giving padding to the child div give a width value in percentage.

**CSS**

```
/* Below are the edited values in your code */
#logo {
    width: 20%;  /* width: 317px; */
}

.topnav a {
    width: 16%;  /* Calculation should be correct */
   /*padding-left: 22px;
   padding-right:22px;*/
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/olezig/1/edit)**